# upload many files and save in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray

Using the API I get 500 pictures, upload them asynchronously. Then I want to keep all these pictures in CoreData, but the application crashes due to insufficient memory.

When upload finished i call method `createFromBlock`

```
+(id)createFromBlock:(MRBlock *)block{
    ManagedBlock *item = [ManagedBlock MR_createInContext:DefaultContext];
    item.id = @(block.id);
    item.name = block.name;
    item.slidesInBlock =  @(block.slidesInBlock);

    item.sizeBlock = block.sizeBlock;
    item.desc = block.desc;
    item.imagePath = block.imagePath;
    item.image = [MRUtils transformedValue:block.image];
    item.price = block.price;
    int i = 0;
    ManagedItem *new = nil;
    for (MRItem *lol in block.items){
        NSLog(@"%i", i);
                        new = [ManagedItem createFromItem:lol];
                new.block = item;
                [item addItemsObject:new];
        new = nil;
        i++;
    }

    [DefaultContext MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveSynchronously completion:nil];

    return item;
}
```

In foreach block.items app is crashed. approximately after 150-160 positions.

If i comment `new = [ManagedItem createFromItem:lol];` - app dont crash

```
+(id)createFromItem:(MRItem *)object{
    ManagedItem *item = [ManagedItem MR_createInContext:DefaultContext];
    item.id = @(object.id);
    item.title = object.title;
    item.detail = object.detail;
    item.imagePath = object.imagePath;
    item.image = [MRUtils transformedValue:object.image];
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing that in some kind of batches ? Or just all at once - 500 in one loop?

Comment: Grzegorz Krukowski, just all at once - 500 in one loop

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not load all your data and then save it.  You should load in small batches, and save each batch.

However, for your specific example, I believe you can get away with turning each object into a fault after saving.

I have never used magical record, and have no idea if it will allow you do to contexty things without calling its methods.  I looked at it once, but it hides way too many details for me... Unless you are doing the most basic things, Core Data can be quite complex, and I want to know everything that is going on with my core data code.

```
+(id)createFromBlock:(MRBlock *)block{
  @autoreleasepool {
    ManagedBlock *item = [ManagedBlock MR_createInContext:DefaultContext];
    item.id = @(block.id);
    item.name = block.name;
    item.slidesInBlock =  @(block.slidesInBlock);

    item.sizeBlock = block.sizeBlock;
    item.desc = block.desc;
    item.imagePath = block.imagePath;
    item.image = [MRUtils transformedValue:block.image];
    item.price = block.price;

    NSUInteger const batchSize = 10;
    NSUInteger count = block.items.count;
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    while (index < count) {
      @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *newObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger batchIndex = 0;
             index < count && batchIndex < batchSize;
             ++index, ++batchIndex) {
          MRItem *lol = [block.items objectAtIndex:index];
          ManagedItem *new = [ManagedItem createFromItem:lol];
          new.block = item;
          [item addItemsObject:new];
          [newObjects addObject:new];
        }
        [DefaultContext MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveSynchronously completion:nil];
        for (NSManagedObject *object in newObjects) {
          // Don't know if MagicalRecord will like this or not...
          [DefaultContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
        }
      }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Basically, that code processes 10 objects at a time.  When that batch is done, the context is saved, and then turns those 10 objects into faults, releasing the memory they are holding.  The auto-release-pool makes sure that any object created in the containing scope are released when the scope exits.  If no other object holds a retain on the objects, then they are deallocated.

This is a key concept when dealing with large numbers or just large objects in Core Data.  Also, understanding the @autoreleasepool is extremely important, though people who have never used MRR do not appreciate its benefit.

BTW, I just typed that into the editor, so don't expect it to compile and run with a simple copy/paste.